# How can I link the mean values to the middle values of the other column repetitively in this data frame?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a file where data is saved in a way that x represents the data value and t represents the time of the data point as below:

```
x1 t1
x2 t2
x3 t3
x4 t4
x5 t5
-----
x6 t6
x7 t7
x8 t8
x9 t9
x10 t10
-----
.
.
.
```

So as you see above, one column holds the data samples and the other holds the time points.

Now what I want to do is I want to take mean value of each five points and associate it with the middle value(not the mean) of the five time points. So that I would have a mean values plot and time will be the middle value.

To make it more clear the new desired array will be like:

```
mean(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) ----> t3
mean(x6, x7, x8, x9, x10) ----> t8
.
.
.
```

I can also use pandas module for this for instance, but couldn't figure out the algorithm.

Comment: Where are you stuck? e.g. did you already read the file? Show what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own data, to show an example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.date_range(start='01-01-2020', end='31-10-2020')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'y': np.random.rand(len(x))
})
df
```

Output

```
             x         y
0   2020-01-01  0.939691
1   2020-01-02  0.835836
2   2020-01-03  0.893328
3   2020-01-04  0.887928
4   2020-01-05  0.393777
..         ...       ...
300 2020-10-27  0.072485
301 2020-10-28  0.797486
302 2020-10-29  0.236217
303 2020-10-30  0.619942
304 2020-10-31  0.471080

[305 rows x 2 columns]
```

To compute the middle timestep and the mean value I group by the index devided by 5 with integer devision

```
df.groupby(df.index // 5).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series([x.x[2], np.mean(x.y)])
)
```

Output

```
            0         1
0  2020-01-03  0.790112
1  2020-01-08  0.700751
2  2020-01-13  0.437752
3  2020-01-18  0.531026
4  2020-01-23  0.597368
..        ...       ...
56 2020-10-09  0.549869
57 2020-10-14  0.589078
58 2020-10-19  0.388551
59 2020-10-24  0.679042
60 2020-10-29  0.439442

[61 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: need to reset_index before performing your logic just in case index is not in order.

Comment: [Ranika Nisal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63922581/14277722) uses groupyby.agg, which is a cleaner way to get a dataframe with the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `agg()` method to aggregate the dataframe. You additionally need to pass in a dictionary to specify the function to be used in aggregating each column

```
N = 5

agg_dictionary = {'data_column': 'mean', 'time_column': lambda col: col.tolist()[N//2]}

df.groupby(df.index // N).agg(agg_dictionary)
```

Comment: I think you don't need to convert ```tolist()```. Works fine with ```df.groupby(df.index // 5).agg({'data_column':'mean', 'time_column': lambda x: x[N // 2]})```

Comment: your current logic will fail at the end group if its size is less than N//2 with out of bounds. replace `N` with `len(col)` in the `agg_dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar enough with pandas to give a clever one-liner solution, so here is a manual solution using a simple loop:

```py
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    averages_over_five = []   # resulting x,t will go here
    current_group = []        # building a group of 5
    for line in f:
        row = line.strip().split()    # splitting on whitespace
        x = int(row[0])       # use float() instead if x is not integer
        t = int(row[1])       # use datetime.datetime.strptime() instead if t is timestamp
        current_group.append((x, t))
        if len(current_group) == 5:
            xaverage = sum(x for x,t in current_group) / 5
            tmiddle = current_group[2][1]
            averages_over_five.append((xaverage, tmiddle))
            current_group = []
if len(current_group) > 0: # if number of lines was not multiple of five, what to do with remainder?
    xaverage = sum(x for x,t in current_group) / len(current_group)
    tmiddle = current_group[len(current_group) // 2][1]
    averages_over_five.append((xaverage, tmiddle))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([t for x,t in averages_over_five], [x for x,t in averages_over_five])
```

Comment: Definitely use mikksu's solution rather than mine. It is better to read a file using pandas than iterating through it manually, as pandas' reader handles a lot of things better than you would; for instance, there might be empty lines at the end of the file, which is not handled correctly by my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution including reading the file. I assume the chunks are really divided by `-`-characters in the file. If not, you could e.g. check `len(values) == 5` instead of looking for the `-`. No special libraries required.

```
def get_mean(values, times):
    return (sum(values) / len(values), times[len(times)//2])

result = []
values = []
times = []
with open("filename", "r") as f:
    for line in f: # read the file line by line
        if line.startswith("-"): # one chunk complete
            result.append(get_mean(values, times))
            values.clear()
            times.clear()
        else: # normal data line
            l = line.split()
            values.append(float(l[0]))
            times.append(l[1])
    if values: # if file doesn't end with ---, append last chunk
        result.append(get_mean(values, times))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(3.0, 't3'), (8.0, 't8')]
```